# How architecture should be for my mobile app

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I'm planning to improve a mobile app as my first mobile and published project and I want to improve a to-do list app. According to this aim I want to use java for backend and one of my friend will improve front-end with flutter.

**The first question is here, can we develop a mobile app with using flutter and java at the same time ?**

If the answer is yes, I am planning to use SQLlite for database but here I am confused :/. I want to use the database for each user own local database.

**How can I deploy a database with my project , the database should work in his/her mobile local. And how the architecture should be?**

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

1. You can develop Flutter app with native (Android or iOS specific) implementations for some platform features. Flutter and native side communicating with [Method Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=ios-channel-swift-tab) (by link you find an official documentation for work with it).
2. Flutter has a [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) plugin that wraps native database realization and giving to you interface for working with SQL database on Flutter side.

Also, if you need tools for communicate with WEB API, Flutter supports it by default. You can find more information in [Fetch data from the internet](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data).

Comment: I think you are telling me to improve your app completely with flutter but ı want to use java in the back-end side. Is that possible

Comment: You can create server on Java and communicate with it from Flutter app by API.